# Drag object based on mouse selection Opengl

Tags: c++, glm-math

What would I need to do in order to select an object with the mouse in OpenGL?  I found something like selection buffer but I also read some where that it was deprecated.  So I'm stuck and do not know what to look for.  Also I'm using C++ do to do this.

Comment: it's called mouse picking and it's complicated.   I have it working, but I just messed around with what I found on this site until it worked -- and mine only works for 2d, not 3d.   http://antongerdelan.net/opengl/raycasting.html  Basically you're shooting a ray "backwards" from the direction you do when you render -- from a screen position back into your world (vs from your world to the screen).   Then, you figure out where it is at different "heights" as it travels to determine what it intersects.  I'd submit this as an answer, but I can't explain anywhere near as well as that website...

Comment: Alright thanks for giving me a starting place and i mainly looking to make it work in 2d so ill play around with this example since it seems to be the only thing out there.

Comment: Since you're doing 2d, I posted my actual code. I admit I don't know exactly how it works and if you have problems, I may not be able to answer them

Answer (score 3):

For 2D, here's the code I have working -- you'll have to modify it a bit, but hopefully it will give you some ideas.  This code gives you the world coordinates at "0 height" -- if something doesn't have 0 height, this may not select it properly depending on perspective.

```
// for the current mouse position on the screen, where does that correspond to in the world?
glm::vec2 World::world_position_for_mouse(const glm::vec2 mouse_position,
                                          const glm::mat4 projection_matrix,
                                          const glm::mat4 view_matrix) 
{
    int window_width;
    int window_height;
    this->graphics.get_window_dimensions(window_width, window_height);

    const int mouse_x = mouse_position[0];
    const int mouse_y = mouse_position[1];

    // normalize mouse position from window pixel space to between -1, 1
    GLfloat normalized_mouse_x =  (2.0f * mouse_x) / window_width - 1.0f;
    float normalized_mouse_y = 1.0f - (2.0f * mouse_y) / window_height;


    glm::vec3 normalized_mouse_vector = glm::vec3(normalized_mouse_x, normalized_mouse_y, 1.0f);

    glm::vec4 ray_clip = glm::vec4(normalized_mouse_vector.xy(), -1.0, 1.0);

    glm::vec4 ray_eye = glm::inverse(projection_matrix) * ray_clip;
    ray_eye = glm::vec4(ray_eye.xy(), -1.0, 0.0);

    glm::vec3 ray_world = (glm::inverse(view_matrix) * ray_eye).xyz();

    ray_world = glm::normalize(ray_world);

    float l = -(camera.z / ray_world.z);


    return {camera.x + l * ray_world.x, camera.y + l * ray_world.y};
}
```

To pan the world by the same "screen units" regardless of zoom, I use this code based on the results of the code above:

```
    float camera_motion = time.get_wall_clock_delta() * camera_motion_per_second;
    auto x1 = this->world_position_for_mouse(glm::vec2(1,0), this->cached_projection_matrix, this->cached_view_matrix).x;
    auto x2 = this->world_position_for_mouse(glm::vec2(0,0), this->cached_projection_matrix, this->cached_view_matrix).x;
    auto camera_change = (x1 - x2) * camera_motion;
```

where `camera_motion` is just a multiplier on how fast you want it to move combined with the time delta from the previous frame.   Basically the further zoomed out you are, the faster this scrolls you per second.  Whatever pixel is on the right edge of your window will take a constant time to get to the left edge regardless of zoom.

Comment: Thanks for the code ill have to play around with it and see what i can come up with appreciate your help.